# ROS Fuerte node communicating with ROS Electric node

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone

I've just started working with ROS Fuerte and I have a bunch of code written for ROS Electric.

Would any one please confirm if nodes written in Fuerte version can communicate with nodes written in Electric version ??

BhanuKiran

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45153/ros-fuerte-node-communicating-with-ros-electric-node/) by [CBK](https://answers.ros.org/users/3317/cbk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2012-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depends on what you mean exactly by 'can communicate with'.

Code written for Electric can always be made to compile on Fuerte, provided that you take care of the necessary changes. Depending on the actual code that might not even be very difficult. I've had multiple packages I could just `rosmake --pre-clean` in a Fuerte shell and they 'just worked'.

If you want to mix binary (as in: already compiled) nodes from Eletric with new ones written for Fuerte, that is not going to work, or at least really not recommended. Message formats could be different between the two, as well as ROS internals, which can (and will) result in either an incorrectly functioning system, or (subtle) bugs. It can be done though, but it depends on actual messages used, use of ROS libraries, etc, etc.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2012-10-04**:
I think from the question it can be implied that the first part of your answer is what he is looking for.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-10-05**:
Right. So, the answer is "don't do that". Recompile your Electric nodes for Fuerte.